# Tabs only mount Tab content on the first time it becomes active

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to load the tab content only on the first time it becomes active, after that the content stays in the DOM

This is what I have

```
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} animation={false} id="my-tabs" mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
    <Tab eventKey={1}>
      <div>content1</div>
    </Tab>
    <Tab eventKey={2}>
      <div>content1</div>
    </Tab>
  </Tabs>
```

it works fine, but there is a lag between switching tabs, since the content I have is quite large and I would like to render it only once, on the first time the tab becomes active.

Is there a way to achieve that? I'm using `react-bootstrap 0.30.10`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**:

apparently `mountOnEnter` must be used with `animation`, otherwise it will not work as intended. I made the change and it works fine now

**Old answer**:

so I have come up with this wrapping component as follow

```
class TabsLazyLoad extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.getInitialState();
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      key: this.props.key || this.props.defaultActiveKey,
      rendered: [],
    };
  }

  addRenderedTab(key) {
    const newState = _.cloneDeep(this.state);
    newState.rendered.push(key);
    this.setState(newState);
  }

  handleSelect(key) {
    this.setState({ key });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs activeKey={this.state.key} onSelect={this.handleSelect} {...this.props}>
        {_.map(this.props.children, (tabComponent) => {
          if (_.includes(this.state.rendered, tabComponent.props.eventKey)) {
            return tabComponent;
          }
          if (tabComponent.props.eventKey === this.state.key) {
            this.addRenderedTab(this.state.key);
          }

          // if it's not rendered, return an empty tab
          const emptyTab = _.cloneDeep(tabComponent);
          emptyTab.props.children = null;
          return emptyTab;
        })}
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}

TabsLazyLoad.propTypes = Tabs.propTypes;
```

It seems to be working fine, but I reckon this is a bit `hacky`, but it's the best I can come up with for now.

Comment: ```mountOnEnter``` worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a good use case for the "Avoid Reconciliation" option that React provides.

[Here's a link to the relevant section in the documentation.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation)

Essentially, there's a lifecycle event called `shouldComponentUpdate` that defaults to true.  When you change it to false, it tells React not to run the component through the standard Reconciliation process (i.e. the "diff" checks).

Like with any lifecycle method, you can create a conditional statement for it.

For a component that should be made completely static after its first render, this is really all you need:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }
  ...
}
```

However, for a more general use case, you'd want to write a conditional statement based on the props and/or the state of the component:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        // Your state
    };
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        // A conditional statement to determine whether
        //    this component should check for updates or not
  }

  render () {
    return (
        <div>
          {/* Your JSX*/}
        </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I think I'll wrap the Tab with componentShouldUpdate lifecycle method and see if I can get around it. Will update the topic as I go along.

Still I think the library should support lazy loading.

Comment: Lazy loading of React components?  That's something that webpack can handle: https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-load-react/

Comment: I don't want to just lazy load a generic component, I would like to lazy load some components that are children of other component. I think it's a bit different than what webpack is doing

Answer (score 0):

I don't use React Boostrap but I guess it's based on the Component design, 
example, the rendered content used TabIndex state. Take a closer look at this sample code:

```
  renderActiveTabContent() {
    const { children } = this.props
    const { activeTabIndex } = this.state
    if (children[activeTabIndex]) {
      return children[activeTabIndex].props.children
    }
  }
```

So the content component render every time Tab state is indexed.

You could use https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs for your solution other wise take a look of those codes to write a simple one, the Component is rendered once and show/hide state via `display:` style attribute.

Hope it's help.

Comment: I only want to have the Tab rendered for the first time it becomes active, so anytime after that, the DOM is already generated and will not be updated again, unless its own state changes. The sample you provided seems to re-render the content each time the tab becomes active though.

Comment: Try to remove `unmountOnExit` in `Tabs`
due to 
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/TabContent.js

line 26-29 
`Unmount tabs (remove it from the DOM) when they are no longer visible`